# Utilizzo dell'espressione "la cattiva strada"

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Una volta ero a cena con un amico italiano e mentre versavo il vino nel suo bicchiere mi ha detto: "tu sei di quelli che ti portano sulla cattiva strada".

Vorrei sapere in quali altri situazioni si può usare questa espressione.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Ciao @Charo e grazie della benvenuta!!!

Comment: @ [random UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29): http://www.pensierocritico.eu/la-cattiva-strada.html

Comment: mmm, ho l'impressione che lo UUID (che vedo io) al posto dello username (che è Tonechas) sia dovuto ad un problema tecnico di StackExchange

Comment: @WalterTross: Veramente è così? Ieri io vedevo il "user name" Tonechas e l'immagine di un giocattolo anatra (si chiama così?). Ma quello che vedo adesso come "user name" è una stringa lunghissima e orribile, probabilmente una random UUID, come tu hai indicato. E il gravatar sembra cambiare col tempo!

Comment: @Charo anche io oggi vedo la stringa lunghissima. *By the way*, in genere si dice "anatra giocattolo", non "giocattolo anatra".

Comment: @WalterTross: Si tratta forse di qualcosa per porre una domanda nel Meta?

Comment: @Charo: Ho segnalato la cosa in "contact us > other". Mi hanno spiegato che è un problema causato da Facebook (lo UUID è di Facebook), che usa male la [API](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) di StackExchange. Per l'occasione hanno corretto il nome utente di Tonechas.

Comment: Ah, grazie, @WalterTross!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***La cattiva/brutta  strada*** si usa spesso in riferimento a cattive abitudini (bere, fumare, drogarsi etc.) che possono essere prese per avere seguito qualcuno che già le pratica. 
L'espressione viene usata anche quando si intraprendono percorsi legati all'illegalità.

[Essere sulla cattiva strada:](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/S/strada.shtml)

> - Fig.: avere un comportamento discutibile, dimostrare propensione a comportamenti immorali o disonesti.
>
>   - Var.: prendere una cattiva strada; prendere una brutta strada.

(Hoepli)

Esempi:

- Da quando ha perso il lavoro ha intrapreso una brutta strada ( attività illegali ).
- Un suo vecchio amico lo ha portato sulla cattiva strada della droga.
- Le brutte compagnie spesso portano i ragazzi sulla brutta strada.

Nel tuo caso specifico penso che il tuo amico abbia usato l'espressione in senso scherzoso.